# UIAccessoryView not showing in sectioned table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm unable to display any accessories in my UITableView cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Foo";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Changing the cell styles shows no difference. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and then creating a new file fixed the problem.

This was a result of having started with an xib file, and then deleted it in favor of doing the whole thing programmatically. Somehow, after deleting the xib, some of the delegation settings stuck.